# Codeigniter function with non exist paramater

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have define a method in controller like

```
public function edit_article($article_id)
{
   $article = $this->articlemodel->find_article($article_id);
   $this->load->view('admin/edit_article',['article'=>$article]);
}
```

But, **I have a only 10 records** in database,which work properly

```
http://[::1]/ci/index.php/admin/edit_article/10
```

But, I have enter manually **enter 100 instead of 10**,  it give error

```
http://[::1]/ci/index.php/admin/edit_article/100
```

ERROR

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: admin/edit_article.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\views\admin\edit_article.php
>   Line: 10 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\admin.php Line: 79
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Help me to handle this problem, **IN Codeigniter**

Comment: show your view and model too

Comment: You can covert id in base64encode post your url.

Comment: Note: I noticed you have not set your base url in codeigniter that why IP is showing. In codeigniter 3 you must set it.